# Syd and Pirate in a relationship?

Tags: plot-explanation, breakfast-with-curtis

In *Breakfast with Curtis*, I can't tell whether Syd is in a relationship with Pirate or they're just house mates. Also, I can't tell who the old lady is in relation to any of them. Are they in a relationship?